# How to use getActiveNetworkInfo() method with API less than 23?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get NetworkInfo but it is possible only on API 23 and higher. What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "fix it"?

Comment: I meant fixing problem with compatibility

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing problem with compatibility"? You can only call that method on API Level 23+ devices. Either do something else all the time, do something else on older devices, or set your `minSdkVersion` to 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, it seems like you are using getActiveNetwork() (which *is* deprecated), and not getActiveNetworkInfo() (which isn't).

Change it to:

```
NetworkInfo nm = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```